# Is there a way to use NodeJS child_process.spawn to run a python application that has imported 3rd-party python packages?

Tags: python, node.js, express

I am trying to run a python script from my NodeJS application using child_process.spawn(). I can get my application to run this python script when it doesn't import a built-in python package, but when I add a 3rd-party python package to the python script, the NodeJS application can no longer run the python script to completion (the server just hangs.) Are there any solutions?

```
// import express JS module into app 
// and creates its variable. 
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 

// Creates a server which runs on port 3000 and  
// can be accessed through localhost:3000 
app.listen(3000, function() { 
    console.log('server running on port 3000'); 
} ) 

// Function callName() is executed whenever  
// url is of the form localhost:3000/name 
app.get('/', callName); 

function callName(req, res) { 

    // Use child_process.spawn method from  
    // child_process module and assign it 
    // to variable spawn 
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn; 

    // Parameters passed in spawn - 
    // 1. type_of_script 
    // 2. list containing Path of the script 
    //    and arguments for the script  

    // E.g : http://localhost:3000/name?firstname=Mike&lastname=Will 
    // so, first name = Mike and last name = Will 
    var process = spawn('python',["./RNN.py" 
] ); 

    // Takes stdout data from script which executed 
    // with arguments and send this data to res object 
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
        res.send(data.toString()); 
    } ) 
}
```

```py
# from pandas import read_csv
from math import sqrt
from datetime import datetime
print("reached")
```

The above python code will not run because of the import pandas but the below code will run:

```py
from math import sqrt
from datetime import datetime
print("reached")
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show me the exact error when you run  with from pandas import read_csv ... ?
is it python 2.7 or 3 ? and 
```import pandas as pd```
```pd.read_csv("data/cereal.csv")``` works by using import this way ?

Comment: If I place the import for pandas in a try/catch block I get the error 'No module named pandas'

Comment: then install pandas from shell !, if you don't have that module installed  , how do you expect it to run ?

Comment: I have pandas installed on my computer, and when I run the python script independently (not through NodeJS) it works fine. I only get the 'no module named pandas' error when I run the python script using child_process

Comment: wait .. i will try in my pc

Comment: node is trying to run python 2.7 but maybe you were usign python 3 when running that import standalone ? and that panda is installed in python 3, try running ```python``` and ```python3``` command in shell and type ```import pandas as pd``` and see which gives you error, maybe you dont have pandas installed in 2.7 version

Comment: that resolved it, thank you!

Comment: cool , versions sometimes are the real deal